# How to mock a global variable within same file

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, mocking, enzyme

I know we can mock the value of a global variable from other file. But, how to mock one when it is within the same testing file?

In the example below, when popupRoot is outside of the functional component, jest will give error. However, it works fine when popupRoot is defined within the functional component.

React File

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const popupRoot = document.getElementById('popup-root') as HTMLElement;

const PopupWrapper = () => {
  //const popupRoot = document.getElementById('popup-root') as HTMLElement;
  useEffect(() => {
    document.body.classList.toggle('noscroll', true);
    return () => {
      if (popupRoot.children.length === 0)
        document.body.classList.toggle('noscroll', false);
    };
  }, []);

  return ReactDOM.createPortal(<p>Hello</p>, popupRoot);
};

export default PopupWrapper;
```

Test file

```
import Enzyme, { mount } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from '@wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17';
import PopupWrapper from './Testing';

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

const toggleClasslist = jest.fn();
Object.defineProperty(document, 'body', {
  value: {
    classList: {
      toggle: toggleClasslist
    }
  },
  writable: true,
  configurable: true
});

window.document.getElementById = jest
  .fn()
  .mockReturnValue(document.createElement('div'));

describe('PopupWrapper component test', () => {
  let wrapper: any;

  beforeAll(() => {
    wrapper = mount(<PopupWrapper />);
  });

  it('should call classList.toggle("noscroll",true) on mount', () => {
    expect(toggleClasslist).toHaveBeenCalledWith('noscroll', true);
  });

  it('should call classList.toggle("noscroll",false) on unmount', () => {
    wrapper.unmount();
    expect(toggleClasslist).toHaveBeenCalledWith('noscroll', false);
  });
});
```

Error
[image: Error]

Comment: It might be because you're creating the `getElementById` mock _after_ importing `PopupWrapper`. Could you try moving the mock above the import statement?

Comment: @AlanFriedman Thanks so much! Moving the mock above import statement solved the issue. But I still have no clue why this solution worked. Could you please provide the explanation on it? –

Comment: Sure, I'll add more detail in an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the `getElementById` mock *before* importing `PopupWrapper` in the test file:

```
window.document.getElementById = jest
  .fn()
  .mockReturnValue(document.createElement('div'));
import PopupWrapper from './Testing';
```

In your example, the contents of the `PopupWrapper` file are parsed and executed before the mock is created. That means that the line `const popupRoot = document.getElementById('popup-root') as HTMLElement;` is called before the mock is created.

The reason it works when inside the `PopupWrapper` function is that the `PopupWrapper` function is called in the `beforeAll` callback (`mount(<PopupWrapper />);`), which is executed after the mock has already been created.

If you're wondering why `jest.mock()` calls don't need to happen before importing the module they mock, the reason is that [calls to `jest.mock()` are hoisted to the top of the file](https://jestjs.io/docs/es6-class-mocks#calling-jestmock-with-the-module-factory-parameter).